# LostFocus event of an Image isn't firing

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an image which displays a delete button when tapped. What I need is for the delete button to disappear when the image has LostFocus.
Typically, for say a textbox I'd just use something like the following.

```
tb.LostFocus += tbOnLostFocus;

private void tbOnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    delBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

My issue is that the same code just isn't firing on an image. I vaguely remember reading somewhere a while ago that LostFocus events wont fire on an image as it isn't a focusable element. Not sure if my memory is correct as I can't find a reference to it now.

Has anyone found a suitable workaround or managed to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `MenuFlyout`. Once the image is tapped it will show delete button. if the pointer is tapped anywhere other than clicking on delete button it will be collapsed

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg" Tapped="Image_Tapped">
      <Image.Resources>
          <MenuFlyout x:Name="DeleteMenuFlyout">
              <MenuFlyout.Items>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="delete"  Click="Delete_Click"   Text="Delete" />
              </MenuFlyout.Items>
          </MenuFlyout>
      </Image.Resources>
 </Image>
```

//C#

```
 private void Image_Tapped(object sender,TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      DeleteMenuFlyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
   }
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll give this a try. Will this work with a list of dynamically created images, without XAML?

Comment: What is the syntax to add Image.Resources in pure C#? I tried the following and a couple of other things to no avail - Im.Resources.Add(DeleteMenuFlyout);

Comment: Simply place the flyout in Page.Resources it will work like the same. You can add the images dynamically to a listview and access the same . If you need a code snippet i will edit my answer

Comment: Ah, of course. Got it. Works fine for my purpose. +1 Thanks